# Document ready not hit on page load, but it works using Developer Tools Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, developer-tools

On Ajax Success, `li` element is appended to `ul`.

```
$.ajax({
           ..
     success: function (response) {
         response.data.forEach(function (x) {
            $("#ulMain").append('<li class="liSub">' + x + '</li>');
     }
});
```

It creates sth like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="liSub">ABC</li>
  <li class="liSub">BCF</li>
</ul>
```

I want the dynamically added `li` elements to fire an alertbox on click.
But the code below is not being hit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".liSub").on("click", function () {
        alert("Fired");
    });
});
```

Interestingly, If I run the `document.ready` section of the code using F12 - Console, it works. What stops it run normally, and lets it run through console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `.` prefix for class and use **event delgation** for created dynamic dom elements

```
$("ul").on("click", '.liSub', function () {
     alert("Fired");
});
```

Comment: Ok use event delegation

Comment: Convinced :) So there is no way to use the dynamically added item's class as a jquery selector?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an element loaded dynamically, try delegating it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click",".liSub", function () {
        alert("Fired");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because when your page is ready, the ajax call is not finished. You can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ulMain").on("click",".liSub", function () {
        alert("Fired");
    });
});
```

It will bind the click to the `#ulMain` which exists at the execution and will delegate the event to `.liSub` at the moment of the click. It creates only one binding which is also better for global performance.